# One hot encoding when reading into tf.dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-datasets

I am running a tensorflow model on the gcp-ai platform. The dataset is large and not everything can be kept in memory at the same time, therefore I read the data into a `tf.dataset` using the following code:

```
def read_dataset(filepattern):
    def decode_csv(value_column):
        cols = tf.io.decode_csv(value_column, record_defaults=[[0.0],[0],[0.0])
        features=[cols[1],cols[2]]
        label = cols[0]
        return features, label
    # Create list of files that match pattern
    file_list = tf.io.gfile.glob(filepattern)
    # Create dataset from file list
    dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(file_list).map(decode_csv)
    return dataset

training_data=read_dataset(<filepattern>)
```

The problem is that the second column in my data is categorical, and I need to use one hot encoding. How can this be done, either in the function `decode_csv` or manipulate the `tf.dataset` later.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [tf.one_hot](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot). Assuming that the second column is `cols[1]` and that the categorical values have been converted to integers, you could do the following:

```
def decode_csv(value_column):
    cols = tf.io.decode_csv(value_column, record_defaults=[[0.0],[0],[0.0]])
    features=[cols[1], tf.one_hot(cols[2], nb_classes)]
    label = cols[0]
    return features, label
```

**NOTE:** Not tested.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunatly this did not work. Also, I see that I need to solve the problem in a completly different wasy.

Comment: Why didn't it work? I'm happy to help you further :)

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply. To me it seems as if the problem is that the return tensor has to have the same shape as the input. And by doing one_hot encoding we are changing the shape of the tensor. See what is written about return value here:https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_csv

Comment: No worries :) I didn't change the call to `tf.io.decode_csv`, so calling `tf.one_hot` after that should not change anything. What is the error message?

Comment: The error message is TypeError: Unsupported return value from function passed to Dataset.map(): None.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that calling tf.one_hot after that should not change anything?

Comment: Oh, alright, now I see what you meant. And you're right - `tf.one_hot` does change the shape of the input tensor. The solution should then be to apply this transformation *after* decoding the csv file. Would something along the lines of `tf.data.TextLineDataset(file_list).map(decode_csv).map(lambda x, y: (tf.one_hot(x[1], nb_classes), y))` make it? (using your original `decode_csv`). Apologies for the misunderstanding

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I still don't understand how this approach could work  if there are several categorical features combined with numeric features. I anyway ended up manipulating the shape in the decode_csv function, since that gave me the possibility to do batching before decode_csv resulting in much faster code.

Comment: You can basically pass any function to `Dataset.map` and TF will apply it to every element of the dataset (I now notice that I should have also returned `x[0]` too). Anyway, nice that you managed to solve it!

Comment: Interesting, when I used `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical` I got a `takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` Error, but, when using `tf.one_hot` instead, it worked like a charm. Thank you.